# What are some odd jobs you can do while working from home?

Tags: working-at-home

I work from home as a software developer and, as a result, I have a flexible schedule and a few hours of downtime each day. I've been thinking it would be nice to earn a little extra money, especially since I could do things while other people need to be at the office / commuting / preparing for work. The two things that jump out at me are driveway snow removal and dog walking - are there any other part-time, casual jobs that people can do while working from home?

Answer (score 3):

Last I checked, software authoring was pretty lucrative. Are you specifically looking to do some non-software work? The two things you mention are among the unskilled work o go after, but with some effort you might be able to use your skills to pick up other work. As a blogger, I've needed help with PHP and the blogging tools, the rate for help was $50/hr. Snow is too seasonal, but the walking surely doesn't pay that much, or does it?

Comment: It's not really for the money. Just for an occasional change of pace. Volunteering is a good idea too.

Comment: Blogging in itself can be a source of income, as opposed to helping other bloggers to make money ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Fiverr](http://fiverr.com/) and [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) comes to my mind.

You won't break the bank, but will give you a nice distraction and earn you some cash for your time.  And you can do this at your own schedule.

Comment: If this is something that interests you, you could deliver meals to senior citizens.  This is voluntary work and you won't get paid, but the job is easy and quick and the satisfaction is priceless.  I forgot what the organization was that I signed up a long time ago, but something you might be interested in.

Comment: That's a good idea